# Table-per-subclass objects with same id collide in cache

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, table-per-subclass

I need to map a legacy table using Fluent NHibernate. I have no control over the table structure.

The table looks like this:

```
TypeId   ObjectId   Data
10       1          ...   //Cat 1
10       2          ...   //Cat 2
20       1          ...   //Dog 1
30       1          ...
```

I am attempting to map this using a table-per-subclass structure using a discriminator value for `TypeId`.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public virtual int ObjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Data { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalMap : ClassMap<Animal>
{
    public AnimalMap()
    {
        Table("MyAnimals");
        Id(x => x.ObjectId);
        Map(x => x.Data);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("TypeId")
            .AlwaysSelectWithValue();
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
}

public class CatMap : SubclassMap<Cat>
{
    public CatMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("10");
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}

public class DogMap : SubclassMap<Dog>
{
    public DogMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("20");
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to load `Cat 1` after `Dog 1`, or vice versa.

```
var a = session.Get<Dog>(1); //Dog1
var b = session.Get<Cat>(1); //null
```

If I evict the first animal before fetching the second, it works.

```
var a = session.Get<Dog>(1); //Dog1
session.Evict(a);
var b = session.Get<Cat>(1); //Cat1
```

When I map both a `Dog` and a `Cat` to my `AnimalHome` class, I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MyNamespace.**Dog**' to type
>   'MyNamespace.**Cat**'.

This leads me to believe that the cache doesn't differentiate the `Dog` and `Cat` by their types. It just thinks of it as `Animal 1` and that *`Cat 1` equals `Dog 1`*.

Can I somehow make the cache take the actual subclass into account? 
Alternatively, if this is not possible with a table-per-subclass structure, how should I approach mapping this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by ditching the Discriminator. 
A `Where` mapping was more appropriate in my case, as I don't actually need to treat the `Dog` or `Cat` as an `Animal` in my code. 
I still keep code duplication to a minimum by inheriting the `Animal`-related mappings.

```
public class AnimalMap<T> : ClassMap<T>
    where T : Animal
{
    public AnimalMap()
    {
        Table("MyAnimals");
        Id(x => x.ObjectId);
        Map(x => x.Data);
    }
}

public class CatMap : AnimalMap<Cat>
{
    public CatMap()
    {
        Where("TypeId = 10");
    }
}
```

The cache now understands that a `Cat` is not a `Dog`.